# Why -lm option is not required in MinGW GCC?

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

Compiler option -lm is required when compiling and linking program containing functions in math.h on Linux GCC, otherwise a link error will appear. However, -lm option is not required in MinGW GCC on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The `-lm` option in't required with MinGW(-w64) because the math functions are already part of MinGW(-w64).